# Simmons-Smith reaction, example reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics

Does this reaction work in theory? It's based on the Simmons–Smith reaction but with ZnCCl$_4$ instead of ZnCH$_2$Cl$_2$.[image]

Comment: I doubt it. S-S is overwhelming done with di-iodo or dibromomethane. Dichloromethane is often used as solvent but does not participate.

Comment: ZnCCl4 is not possible. At least, I don't know. Can you link me where did you find this compound? $\ce{ZnCH2Cl2}$ also does not exist as a sole compound as it is a [carbenoid intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organozinc_compound) made from the reaction of DCM and zinc. $$\ce{2CH2Cl2 + 2Zn -> [2ClCH2ZnCl] <=> (ClCH2)2Zn + ZnCl2}$$

Comment: @NilayGhosh I didn't see it anywhere. My thought was that if $\ce{ZnCH2Cl2}$ makes a compound with 2 hydrogens, $\ce{ZnCCl4}$ would make a compound with 2 chloride atoms attached.

Comment: But that compound isn't possible.